# using an if statement or function as a switch case

Tags: javascript

is it possible to do an if statement in a switch case? or using `$.isNumeric` funciton ?

I've tried several goes in jsfiddle and it didnt seem to work.

```
var someVar  = 1;
switch(someVar){
    case someVar < 0:
        console.log('asdasd');
        break;        
}
```

this didnt seem to work, is ther another way?

http://jsfiddle.net/RLxpU/

Comment: Nope, you can't use a condition as a case, as it evaluates to a boolean

Comment: @adeneo: your phrase sounds a bit vague - "can't use a condition as a case, as it evaluates to a boolean" --- actually one can use **any expression** as a `case` argument, but the `switch` argument should keep that in mind

Comment: @adeneo All conditions evaluate as booleans, including `someVar < 0`.

Comment: @adeneo well if the expression in the head of the `switch` evaluates to boolean too ...

Comment: That's basically what I meant, it doesn't match the switch as it evaluates to `true`, not a number, but you can of course use almost anything in the case, as long as it matches the switch. Badly formulated.

Comment: The thing is, if you're just checking a boolean condition, it's silly to not just use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch is certainly capable of evaluating expressions and conditions: you just have to pass switch the right thing to evaluate:

```
switch ( true ) {

    case someVar < 0:
        console.log('asdasd');
        break;

}
```

Will work since the expression `someVar < 0` evaluates to `true` == the value switch is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you can't use a condition as a case, as it evaluates to a boolean, which doesn't match the switch, try this to see

```
var someVar  = 1;
switch(false){
    case someVar < 0: // false, someVar is not less than zero
        console.log('asdasd');
        break;        
}

switch(true){
    case someVar > 0: // now it's true, someVar is more than zero
        console.log('asdasd');
        break;        
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RLxpU/1/)

Comment: This works, but (and this isn't a comment on your *answer*, just the practice) it's like the goofiest thing ever.

Comment: @Pointy - I agree, I wouldn't use it myself, but to see how it works it's a good example.

Comment: While `switch(false)` certainly leads to the execution of the case in this code, using `false` as your condition generally leads to "reversing" any case expressions - confusing code in the general case

Comment: @BrianNorth - It's not that confusing, just bad form.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others have shown, you can also pass the expression.

```
var someVar  = -1;
switch(someVar < 0){
  case true:
    console.log('true');
    break;    
  case false:
    console.log('false');
    break; 
  }
```